# Cmake link static lib against shared one

Tags: c, cmake, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I'm new to CMake and I don't really know what I'm doing ...
I am currently trying to link a static library (libavcodec.a) against a shared one (GreenVideo). I keep having errors saying that my functions provided by my static lib are "undefined reference". My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
PROJECT(GreenVideo)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/)

link_directories(/home/nde/svn/Visio/trunk/applications/dorsalistaApp/components/GreenVideo/lib)


ADD_LIBRARY( GreenVideo SHARED
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/libavcodec/xvmc.h
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/libavcodec/vdpau.h
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/libavcodec/dxva2.h
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/libavcodec/avfft.h
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/libavcodec/dv_profile.h
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/libavcodec/vaapi.h
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/libavcodec/vda.h
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/libavcodec/version.h

            metadatagen.h metadatagen.cpp

            greenvideofactory.h
            greenvideofactory.cpp
        )



target_link_libraries(GreenVideo /home/nde/svn/Visio/trunk/applications/dorsalistaApp/components/GreenVideo/lib/libavcodec.a)
```

Is there anything suspicious in the way I'm doing it ?

Regards,
Nicolas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **static library** obviously has some `undefined references`. Static library does not store the information about how those reference can be resolved, unlike **shared library** (.so).

In fact, **static library** is just an arcive, a collection of **objecf files** (.o).

To fix your issues you must add more link libraries afrer `.../ibavcodec.a`. All the libraries that `libavcodec.a` may need, such as for example: `c`, `stdc++`, `rt` etc..

Edit:

Okay, it seems i figured out your problem. It's not with the way you link your library, it's because of the way you include `libavcodec`'s header files.

Where you include header file like:

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
```

you must do

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}
```

You can also wrap many includes in one `extern "C" {` ... `}` like:

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/common.h>
...
}
```

---

What's the problem? C++ symbols have [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). So your linker looks for C++ symbols in `libavcodec.a` but those are not there.

Comment: Well the only error message I'm having is this one:
    CMakeFiles/GreenVideo.dir/metadatagen.cpp.o: In function `CMetaDataGen::AVC_parser(unsigned char*, unsigned int)':
    metadatagen.cpp:(.text+0x4e0): undefined reference to `av_init_packet(AVPacket*)'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [components/GreenVideo/lib/libGreenVideo.so] Error 1



So I guess CMake is not able to find the library (ibavcodec.a). Otherwise, it would be asking for the standard c library ....

I have opened the link.txt file which gather all the information about linking flags.

Comment: Thank you ! I don't know how you manage to see this, but that was the solution ! Regards, Nicolas

Comment: @SyfIllis You can see this from `av_init_packet(AVPacket*)`. This is clearly C++ signature of a function because it includes type (`AVPacket*`).